# Perceptron algorithm does not converge correctly

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, perceptron

Given the following labelled data:

```
feature_matrix = np.array \
    (
        [
            [   1,    1],
            [   2,    3],
            [   3,    4],
            [-0.5, -0.5],
            [  -1,   -2],
            [  -2,   -3],
            [  -3,   -4],
            [  -4,   -3]
        ]
    )

labels = np.array \
    (
        [
             1,
             1,
             1,
            -1,
            -1,
            -1,
            -1,
            -1
        ]
    )
```

The idea is to run the linear perceptron algorithm through the labelled data until **convergence** in order to find the resulting parameter θ and offset parameter θ<sub>0</sub>. For reference, here is the perceptron function I wrote in python:

```
def perceptron(feature_matrix, labels, convergence=True):

    # initialize theta and theta_0 to zero
    theta = np.zeros(len(feature_matrix[0])); theta_0 = 0

    while convergence:
        for i in range(len(feature_matrix)):

            exit = True

            if (labels[i] * np.dot(feature_matrix[i], theta) <= 0):

                theta   = theta   + labels[i] * feature_matrix[i]
                theta_0 = theta_0 + labels[i]

                exit = False

        if exit: break

    return (theta, theta_0)
```

I have used this code before, and can confirm that it works. The `exit` flag makes sure that the loop breaks if there are no mistakes, however, the resulting parameters apparently are not correct. So, the perceptron algorithm is initialised with the parameters to zero, i.e θ=[0,0] and θ<sub>0</sub>=0. The first datapoint to be explored is (1,1). Below are the values the function returns after it converges:

```
parameters = perceptron(feature_matrix, labels)

print('Theta_0:', parameters[-1])
print('Theta  :', parameters[0].tolist())

# Theta_0: 1
# Theta  : [1.0, 1.0]
```

These values seem off, since the decision boundary sits right on top of the datapoint (-0.5,-0.5) as can be seen in a desmos graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t7s9xguks4). I also figured that if I change the order, say the first datapoint to be explored be (2,3), then:

```
parameters = perceptron(feature_matrix, labels)

print('Theta_0:', parameters[-1])
print('Theta  :', parameters[0].tolist())

# Theta_0: 1
# Theta  : [2.0, 3.0]
```

Regardless of the order of iteration, it seems like the perceptron algorithm takes the first values as resulting parameters, and does not make any mistakes afterwards as per this conditional clause `(labels[i] * np.dot(feature_matrix[i], theta) <= 0)`.

Why is this is happening and what should be the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start from the begining. Your `exit=True` should be outside your loop over examples as you want to exit iff **all samples are correctly labeled**. Currently you will exit as soon as the last one is correctly labeled.

Second issue is that while you are updating theta_0 you are not actually using it in your criterion. Luckily for this dataset you do not need a bias as an optimal classifier crosses the origin.

Finally, (1, 1) **is the correct solution** because of forgeting about theta_0! (so if theta_0=0, then indeed theta=(1,1) works fine), since it means "classify as positive class if and only if sum of features is positive", and for your points

```
feature_matrix = np.array \
    (
        [
            [   1,    1],  # positive sample ; positive sum ; CORRECT
            [   2,    3],  # positive sample ; positive sum ; CORRECT
            [   3,    4],  # positive sample ; positive sum ; CORRECT
            [-0.5, -0.5],  # negative sample ; negative sum ; CORRECT
            [  -1,   -2],  # negative sample ; negative sum ; CORRECT
            [  -2,   -3],  # negative sample ; negative sum ; CORRECT
            [  -3,   -4],  # negative sample ; negative sum ; CORRECT
            [  -4,   -3]   # negative sample ; negative sum ; CORRECT
        ]
    )
```

After fixing theta_0 you will also end up with a different solution, theta=(1.5, 1.5), theta_0=0 which is also correct
[image]
In general there are infinitely many solutions that perceptron might end up in.

Note, that the classical perceptron algorithm converges (not just numerically, but actually **stops and succeeds with 100% accuracy**) with no learning rates, etc. as long as your data is **linearly separable**, and this dataset clearly is.

So the final code will look something like this:

```
def perceptron(feature_matrix, labels, convergence=True):

    # initialize theta and theta_0 to zero
    theta = np.zeros(len(feature_matrix[0]));
    theta_0 = 0

    while convergence:
        # FIRST FIX, initialisation outside the loop
        exit = True
        for i in range(len(feature_matrix)):
            # SECOND FIX, theta_0 used in error criterion
            if (labels[i] * (np.dot(feature_matrix[i], theta) + theta_0) <= 0):
                theta   = theta   + labels[i] * feature_matrix[i]
                theta_0 = theta_0 + labels[i]

                exit = False

        if exit: break

    return (theta, theta_0)
```

Comment: Yes @lejlot this is absolutely correct. I just managed to get the same results after reading the lecture notes at MIT [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.S097/www/resources/L01.pdf). I saw that I did not take into account the offset parameter θ<sub>0</sub> in the conditional clause. The parameters should be as you pointed out theta=(1.5, 1.5), theta_0=0. Thank you for your time explaining, I don't have enough reputation though this answer definitely deserves an upvote :)

Comment: I have a follow up question just for my understanding @lejlot .  Assuming there is no offset parameter like in my original function, and say we initialise theta to be positive values only, i.e. non-zero initialisation. What is the minimum number of errors the perceptron algorithm would make? Perhaps you could provide some insight on this, or maybe it's even worthy of posting a new question related to errors. Thanks!

Comment: That definitely is a very different question. And it is very example specific, perceptron algorithm is pretty chaotic. For this data if you init theta to positive values then you will likely get 0 errors from the get go. As you see from the code, (1.5, 1.5) is a solution, but so is any (a, a) for a>0  in fact any (a, b) is a solution here for a, b > 0

Comment: Thank you @lejlot for your feedback. I can confirm that after initialising the perceptron's theta to be any number 1 and 100 (same feature data and labels), the minimum error is 0. I actually generated the numpy array of thetas using `itertools` and ran the perceptron algorithm through all possible combination of numbers 1 and 100. Also, I wanted to post a new question but stackoverflow did not let me because I "asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community" :(

Answer (score 1):

"I have used this code before, and can confirm that it works".

Your code is never supposed to work. Here's why - the entire theory of perceptron algorithm is based on four things:

1. forward pass of the data through the perceptron
2. activation function
3. error computation
4. backpropagation of error

Your code only has the first one, but the last three are missing. Those three components are arguably the most important parts of a perceptron network. You also need to have a learning rate, since just backpropagating the entire error will never lead to convergence of the network.

The following code is based on [this Medium.com article](https://towardsdatascience.com/perceptron-algorithm-in-python-f3ac89d2e537). It explains the theory of the perceptron network in detail and I suggest that you go through it.

The activation function had to be a [tanh function](https://machinelearningmastery.com/choose-an-activation-function-for-deep-learning/#:%7E:text=Tanh%20Hidden%20Layer%20Activation%20Function&text=1%20to%201.-,The%20larger%20the%20input%20(more%20positive)%2C%20the%20closer%20the,x%20%2B%20e%5E%2Dx)) since your labels are 1 and -1.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def activation_function(x):
    return (np.exp(x) - np.exp(-x)) / (np.exp(x) + np.exp(-x))


def perceptron(feature_matrix, labels, learning_rate, tolerance=1e-5):
    _, num_features = feature_matrix.shape
    theta = np.zeros(num_features + 1)

    previous_error = 0
    errors = []

    while True:
        current_error = 0

        for index, sample in enumerate(feature_matrix):
            sample = np.insert(sample, 0, 1)
            y_hat = activation_function(np.dot(sample, theta))

            if y_hat - labels[index] != 0:
                theta += learning_rate * ((labels[index] - y_hat) * sample)
                current_error += y_hat - labels[index]

        errors.append(current_error)

        if abs(previous_error - current_error) <= tolerance:
            break

        previous_error = current_error

    return theta, errors


feature_matrix = np.array(
    [[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4], [-0.5, -0.5], [-1, -2], [-2, -3], [-3, -4], [-4, -3]]
)

labels = np.array([1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])

parameters, errors = perceptron(feature_matrix, labels, 1e-2)

print("Theta_0:", parameters[0])
print("Theta  :", parameters[1:].tolist())

plt.plot(errors)
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Error")
plt.title("Error vs Epoch")
plt.show()
```

This gave me the following output:

```
Theta_0: -0.6057138254036737
Theta  : [1.4919048872642444, 1.6402462207966715]
```

You can also see that the error is decreasing over time.

[image: Error vs Epoch]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mahieyin-rahmun . Setting a tolerance value doesn't necessarily ensure 100% convergence or am I wrong? It just sets the error rate very very low basically close to zero as per  the parameter `tolerance=1e-5`.

Comment: (a) Convergence doesn't mean you have an error of 0. Convergence means that the model has reached a state where training it further will not make it gain significant performance gains. As you can see from the graph, the error has become a flat line after 1000 epochs. You could continue to train the model, but it will not give you better results than it already is giving you, a.k.a a point of diminishing returns. (b) Due to how floating point numbers work in computers, you will never be able to reach an error of 0, you will have some trailing digits, e.g. 0.000000000000000000000123 ≈
 0

Comment: The original perceptron algorithm does not need any of these things, you are confusing perceptron algorithm with later ideas of MLP learning based on derivatives